# React class: setState does nothing (and no errors reported)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have a React class with this constructor:

```
class AddList extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = { hidden: true };
}
```

Then I have this function:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
e.preventDefault(); // this prevents the page from reloading -- do not     delete this line!

// Implement the rest of this function here!
alert('this.state.hidden: ' + this.state.hidden);
if (this.state.hidden == true){
  alert('setting hidden to false');
  this.setState({hidden: false});
  }
  else{
    alert('setting hidden to true');
    this.setState({hidden: true});
  }
alert('this.state.hidden: ' + this.state.hidden);
    . . . 

My problem is that neither this.setState({hidden: false);
nor                        this.setState({hidden: 'false');
```

Changes the state!
The 'alert' boxes confirm the path through the code and ONLY 'setState' seems to be a NOP!

Comment: "ONLY 'setState' seems to be a NOP!". What do you mean?

Comment: can we see the full file of what you are trying to do? it's not clear with these snippets.

Comment: if something is not working, there will be a valid reason behind it, in this case reason is: "setState behaviour is async" :)

Answer (score 2):

`setState` is asynchronous and therefore you won't be able to see the updates afterwards. That's why you don't see the up to date value on your last `alert` call.

For more information check ReactJs's doc: 
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

I wrote a sample code based on yours:

```js
class AddList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    
    this.state = { hidden: true }
    
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }
  
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    
    this.setState({ hidden: !this.state.hidden })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>State value: {this.state.hidden ? 'hidden' : 'visible'}</div>
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Click-me</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
 }
 
 ReactDOM.render(<AddList />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: *correction `setState` is asynchronous

Answer (score 2):

In case if you want to read the state values after updating it, you can use the second argument of setState method which is a callback function. This callback function executes after the state is updated and component is re-rendered. For ex. 
`this.setState({ hidden: !this.state.hidden }, function(){ console.log("updated state: " + this.state.hidden); });`